# Looping through list in ranges

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of 200 elements, i want to loop through the list in increments of 10.

1. Result 1 = list[0:10]
2. Result 2 = list[11:21]
3. Result 3 = list[22:32]
4. Result 20 = list[190:199]

Whats the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Your example list has 201 elements.

Comment: I strongly suspect that using 20 individual variables is not going to be a good long-term solution for you.  Also, note that your sample lists are 11 elements long.

Comment: @Prune using 10 at a time is a great long-term solution for what im trying, why do you suspect otherwise? Maybe I'm missing some preconceived notion.

Comment: Please read my comment again; I didn't question grabbing 10 elements at a time.

Comment: @prune still not understadning, please clarify "20 individual variables", are you talking about the partitioning of the list into 20 sublists? If thats the case, my original comment stands.

Comment: What @Prune is suggesting is that for a collection of similar things, you probably don't want to assign them to individually named variables (like `Result11`), but you want a structure to hold them, like a list, such as`Results = []`, and then you don't need 20 literal names, but can do `Results[11]`, `Results[5]`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to split your list into chunks:

```
chunks = [xlist[x:x+10] for x in range(0, len(xlist), 10)]

for chunk in chunks:
    print(len (chunk)) # prints out  10
```